# Manejo de archivos

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo txt de paises con habitantes

```
Argentina, 35474823
Brasil, 24859503
Chile, 10283474
```

Y hay que agregarle la cantidad de nacimientos que hay en cada pais

```
lista= [] # Lista vacía.
eleg_pais = input("Elegir país que desea actualizar: ") # Elegir el país.
nuev_hab = int(input("Ingresar la cantidad de nuevos habitantes: ")) #Cantidad de habitantes.
#Cargamos el archivo en memoria
archivo= open("registros.txt", "r") # El "with" cerrará solo el archivo.
# Reemplazamos los datos que queremos.
lineas = archivo.readlines()
# Ejecutamos el cambio que queremos hacer
for linea in archivo: 
    linea= linea.rstrip("\n")
    pais, habitantes, nacimientos = linea.split(",") # Dividimos cada linea en variables.
    nacimientos = int(nuev_hab)
    lista2= [pais, habitantes, nacimientos]
    lista.append(lista2)

print("Los nacimientos son:", lista2)
archivo.close()
```

No se en que parte de mi planteo me estoy equivocando

Comment: No entiendo para qué abres varias preguntas idénticas

Comment: Porque anteriormente habia planteado mal el problema. Y no puedo borrar las consultas que hago

Comment: Entonces, edita la pregunta e incluye la nueva información relevante.

Comment: Anteriormente habia pensado que a los habitantes habia que sumarle los nuevos nacimientos, pero es una columna aparte. Y ahi cambia el codigo

Comment: No sabia que se podia hacer eso, es el primer dia que estoy dentro de la pagina. Disculpa.

Comment: Dale, lamento si el comentario sonó serio. Espero que podamos ayudarte con tu código!

Comment: Muchas gracias, trate de hacerle modificaciones pero sigue estando mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola de nuevo :P Empecemos con los errores:

- 1: Has eliminado el `with` para cerrar el archivo más tarde con
  `archivo.close()`. Sin embargo lo cierras demasiado tarde. Se
  aconseja usar `with` porque el programa cerrará el archivo al acabar
  de usarlo (es decir, después de ejecutar todo lo que haya dentro de
  la siguiente identación), es innecesario tener el archivo abierto
  tanto tiempo.
- 2: Si `lineas` es `archivos.readlines()` ¿por qué ignoras eso y después utilizas la variable `archivo` de nuevo?
- 3: Si has leído los datos de `nacimiento` dentro de la
  `linea`, ¿por qué lo reemplazas por los de habitantes de tu `input`?
- 4: Confundes los datos con las `strings`. El resultado de `lista2 = [pais, habitantes, nacimientos]` **no es** `Argentina, 10000, 100`. Es `Argentina10000100` porque las comas no son `strings` en esa linea. Es por eso que usamos la función `format` (por favor usa google para entender la función format de python: http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/inputoutput.html ).

Ahora la solución:

```
lista= [] # Lista vacía.
eleg_pais = input("Elegir país que desea actualizar: ") # Elegir el país.
nuev_hab = int(input("Ingresar la cantidad de nuevos habitantes: ")) # Cantidad de nacimientos.
#Cargamos el archivo en memoria
with open("registros.txt", "r") as archivo:
    lineas = archivo.readlines()
# Nota: Aqui el archivo ya está cerrado, eso es lo que hace with.

# Ejecutamos el cambio que queremos hacer
encontrado = False
for index, linea in enumerate(lineas):
    datos = linea.split(",") # Rompemos la string sin saber cuantos datos hay.
    pais = None
    if len(datos) == 2: # Si solo hay dos datos (pais, habitantes), creamos nacimientos
        pais, habitantes = datos # Dividimos cada linea en variables.
        nacimientos = nuev_hab

    elif len(datos) == 3: # Si hay tres datos (pais, habitantes, nacimientos), sumamos nacimientos
        pais, habitantes, nacimientos = datos # Dividimos cada linea en variables.
        nacimientos = int(nacimientos) + nuev_hab

    if eleg_pais == pais: # Buscamos la linea donde el pais coincida con nuestro pais elegido.
        lineas[index] = "{0}, {1}, {2}".format(pais, int(habitantes), nacimientos) # Y actualizamos los datos.
        print("Los nacimientos de {0} son: {1}".format(pais, nacimientos))
        encontrado = True
        break

if encontrado: # Solo guardamos el archivo si hemos cambiado algo. No lo guardamos si te has equivocado al escribir el nombre de un pais.
    with open("registros.txt", "w") as guardando:
        guardando.write("\n".join(lineas))
    print("Datos actualizados.")
else:
    print("Ese pais no he podido encontrarlo.")
```

**Notas:**

- Usamos la función `enumerate` porque te da un `index`, sino no puedes
  editar una lista. Al usar esta función no necesitamos crear una nueva
  lista (lista2) ya que podemos editar la que estamos utilizando.
- Lee todos los comentarios que he añadido en cada linea. Si no entiendes
  una linea, busca información hasta que la entiendas y no pases a la
  siguiente.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89573/discussion-on-answer-by-saelyth-manejo-de-archivos).